# Rive animation taking too long to load with RangeError (index): Invalid value: The valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter, animation, rive

Create an empty project and load the below file using the

[all_animations.riv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T9r6qRZPx1liov4cdfpYzWByrhn8mQ9O/view?usp=sharing)

Code :

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Artboard? _riveArtBoard;
  StateMachineController? _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initArtBoard();
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _initArtBoard() async {
    if (_riveArtBoard == null) {
      final riveByteData = await rootBundle.load("assets/rive/all_animations.riv");
      RiveFile riveFile = RiveFile.import(riveByteData);
      _riveArtBoard = riveFile.mainArtboard;
    }

    _controller = StateMachineController.fromArtboard(_riveArtBoard!, 'buddy-V2') as StateMachineController;

    _controller!.isActive = true;
    _riveArtBoard!.addController(_controller!);

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Rive Animation"),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: _riveArtBoard == null
          ? const Center(
              child: CupertinoActivityIndicator(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            )
          : Rive(
              artboard: _riveArtBoard!,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              useArtboardSize: true,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

LogCat:

```
The following RangeError was thrown during paint():
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Rive Rive:file:///Users/Downloads/new_animation/lib/views/animated_eyes_view.dart:347:26
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:264:36)
#1      Text._buildRenderStyles (package:rive/src/rive_core/text/text.dart:264:41)
#2      Text.update (package:rive/src/rive_core/text/text.dart:558:7)
#3      Artboard.updateComponents (package:rive/src/rive_core/artboard.dart:153:21)
#4      Artboard.advance (package:rive/src/rive_core/artboard.dart:213:9)
#5      RiveRenderObject.advance (package:rive/src/rive.dart:258:17)
#6      RiveRenderBox.paint (package:rive/src/rive_render_box.dart:353:10)
#7      RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#8      PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#9      RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#10     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#11     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#12     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2882:15)
#13     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1040:7)
#14     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#15     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#16     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#17     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#18     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#19     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#20     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#21     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#22     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2882:15)
#23     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1040:7)
#24     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#25     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#26     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2882:15)
#27     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1040:7)
#28     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#29     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#30     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2882:15)
#31     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:408:5)
#32     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#33     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#34     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#35     _RenderInkFeatures.paint (package:flutter/src/material/material.dart:662:11)
#36     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#37     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#38     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#39     RenderPhysicalModel.paint.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2043:15)
#40     PaintingContext.pushClipRRect (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:575:14)
#41     RenderPhysicalModel.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2030:21)
#42     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#43     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#44     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2882:15)
#45     RenderFlex.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:1040:7)
#46     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#47     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#48     _RenderColoredBox.paint (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:7813:15)
#49     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#50     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#51     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#52     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#53     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#54     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#55     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#56     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#57     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#58     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#59     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#60     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#61     RenderTransform.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2537:17)
#62     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#63     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#64     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2882:15)
#65     RenderStack.paintStack (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:640:5)
#66     RenderStack.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:656:7)
#67     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#68     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#69     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#70     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#71     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#72     _RenderLayoutBuilder.paint (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:333:15)
#73     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#74     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#75     RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2882:15)
#76     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:408:5)
#77     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#78     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#79     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#80     _RenderInkFeatures.paint (package:flutter/src/material/material.dart:662:11)
#81     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#82     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#83     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#84     RenderPhysicalModel.paint.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2043:15)
#85     PaintingContext.pushClipRRect (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:575:14)
#86     RenderPhysicalModel.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2030:21)
#87     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#88     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#89     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#90     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#91     PaintingContext.paintChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:250:13)
#92     RenderProxyBoxMixin.paint (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:129:13)
#93     RenderObject._paintWithContext (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3208:7)
#94     PaintingContext._repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:166:11)
#95     PaintingContext.repaintCompositedChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:109:5)
#96     PipelineOwner.flushPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1156:31)
#97     PipelineOwner.flushPaint (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1166:15)
#98     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:593:23)
#99     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:986:13)
#100    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:457:5)
#101    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1325:15)
#102    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1255:9)
#103    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:5)
#104    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
#105    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:383:5)
#106    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RiveRenderObject#945f0
...  parentData: <none>
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=485.0, h=373.1)
...  size: Size(485.0, 373.1)
RenderObject: RiveRenderObject#945f0
  parentData: <none>
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=485.0, h=373.1)
  size: Size(485.0, 373.1)
```

Comment: You did not grant access to everyone for your rive animation on your Google drive.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with flutter web (on chrome) but not flutter linux [edit: Rive in its current form does not support targeting linux - simple answer]. I don't know what platform you are targeting, but you can try this:

Instead of

```
      final riveByteData =
          await rootBundle.load('assets/rive/all_animations.riv');
      RiveFile riveFile = RiveFile.import(riveByteData);
```

Use:

```
      final RiveFile riveFile =
          await RiveFile.asset('assets/rive/all_animations.riv');
```

Why?

This page here, https://github.com/rive-app/rive-flutter/issues/337, says that the Rive Text engine is only initialized "when necessary". But when you look into the `RiveFile.import` method, it does not check that. Luckily, the `RiveFile.asset` method does start the font engine. (You can easily look into the code of the `RiveFile` class when you click on the class name for example in Visual Studio Code while pressing CTRL).

Why does it not work on linux? I'll try to find out ...
[Edited: Rive in its current version 0.12.4 is not supporting linux as a target platform - simple answer.]

---

This is an alternative approach that also worked well on flutter web:

```
void _onRiveInit(Artboard artboard) {
    final controller =
        StateMachineController.fromArtboard(artboard, 'buddy-V2');
    artboard.addController(controller!);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Simple Animation'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RiveAnimation.asset(
          'assets/rive/all_animations.riv',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          onInit: _onRiveInit,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I also tried that. In some devices, it works, and in others, it's not working. I'm targeting Android tablets and iPads

Comment: Does your Rive animation contain any text? It doesn't look like it for me. It would just be a bit of a workaround, but could you somehow exclude any text in the Rive editor, so that it would not need to start that Rive text engine at all?

Comment: I added an alternative approach with RiveAnimation.asset, see edited answer. Does this work any better?

Comment: Thanks, I excluded the text from the rive editor and it works